# Apache won't start in Windows 10

Tags: apache

I got a new Windows 10 PC and installed XAMPP, but Apache won't start.  There is no "World Wide Web Publishing Service" in the "Services" tab - that's not the problem.  How do I get Apache to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype has taken over port 80.

In Skype, go to: Tools > Options > Advanced tab > Connections,  uncheck "Use port 80 and 443...", and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. When you start your XAMPP, you will get an error message in the log box below your control buttons. It will tell you that another process is using that port with a given PID.

So, what you can do is, open Task Manager and go to Details and then sort the order by PID, then find the given PID and end the task.

Comment here if you need more details. I shall share it with screenshots!